# Picking out multiple keys from an array

Tags: associations, filtering

I have an imported data set that I've used `GroupBy` on to be organized by specific elements of the sublists within the data. These keys are strings of numbers (in particular, they are grouped by day and then by the hour, which is `#[[2, 3]]`, and `#[[2, 4]]` respectively). I am now trying to pick out various keys from these new associations. Here is what a piece of the array looks like:

```
{{string1}, {2016, 3, 4, 0, 0}}
```

So, if I wanted to examine every piece of information from the 4th day of March, I could do `Key["4"]`, which yields:

```
<|"0" -> {{string1}, {2016, 3, 4, 0, 0}} |>
```

I can pick them out individually like this to look at with just the `Key` function, but what I would like to do is pick out several keys to examine a range of days. I've tried using `Keys`, but it doesn't seem to take just a key argument, and going through the whole data set to grab the explicit key values isn't a viable option. Is there an easier way to pick out multiple keys?

Comment: Check `Lookup` in the documentation.

Comment: Thanks, this function is very useful; I am still trying to get a hang of all these new functions introduced in MMa 10. I have some thoughts about `Lookup`, which I'll put as an answer. It might help someone else

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At István's suggestion, I checked out the `Lookup` function, and was able to find a solution:

```
Lookup[#, ToString/@Range[10], Nothing[]]&
```

This takes the association that was previously created by `GroupBy`, and returns back the keys at the first level (which are strings corresponding to the days of the month) 1-10. Any key that doesn't return a value is dropped. My only qualm about this is that it doesn't return the actual keys, just the key values; from an organizational standpoint, this makes things a bit messier, but it's something I can live without for now.

`Lookup` is very robust, and it would be easy to apply it to multiple levels if you have a nested association.

Answer (score 3):

Regarding `Lookup` you wrote:

> My only qualm about this is that it doesn't return the actual keys, just the key values; from an organizational standpoint, this makes things a bit messier, but it's something I can live without for now.

I believe you want [`KeyTake`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/KeyTake.html).  Recreating your situation:

```
SeedRandom[1]

dat = {RandomChoice[List /@ {"a", "b", "c"}, 15], 
    RandomInteger[4, {15, 5}]}\[Transpose];

asc = GroupBy[dat, Extract[{2, 3}]];

KeyTake[asc, Range[2, 5]]
```

> ```
> <|2 -> {{{"b"}, {4, 0, 2, 4, 0}}, {{"a"}, {1, 0, 2, 0, 3}}, {{"b"}, {0, 4, 2, 3, 
>      1}}, {{"b"}, {3, 1, 2, 0, 4}}}, 
>  3 -> {{{"a"}, {0, 2, 3, 3, 2}}, {{"c"}, {2, 4, 3, 0, 3}}, {{"a"}, {2, 0, 3, 1, 
>      2}}},
>  4 -> {{{"a"}, {0, 0, 4, 2, 2}}, {{"a"}, {2, 3, 4, 3, 0}}, {{"a"}, {1, 3, 
>      4, 4, 2}}, {{"a"}, {0, 3, 4, 1, 3}}, {{"a"}, {3, 4, 4, 2, 0}}, {{"b"}, {4, 4, 
>      4, 4, 1}}}|>
> ```

Note that key `5` does not exist in the data so it is simply not returned; there is no need to use `Nothing` to remove it.